# Pylint: func.max is not callable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, max, pylint, func

In my python code, I import func...

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func
```

Then, during my code I select data from a database table...

```
select(func.max(MyTable.my_datetime))
```

...where my_datetime is a DateTime data type...

```
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime

my_datetime = Column('my_datetime', DateTime)
```

The code runs OK, but in the vscode editor I am getting the following error...

**func.max is not callable Pylint(E1102:not-callable)**

I don't want to ignore this if there is a genuine concern behind this Pylint error.

Should I be concerned by this error or can I safely ignore it?

Comment: See https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/9189

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Pylint error you have (`func.max is not callable Pylint(E1102:not-callable)`) is a false positive and you can ignore it in your case.

Pylint is flagging `func.max` not callable because it can't analyze the func object statically and determine that it has a max method.

You can use

```
func: Callable
```

after importing .

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following comment in a line  before the line where you get the error.

```
# pylint: disable=not-callable
```